# Google PlaceDetectionClient vs FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, google-places, google-location-services

My Android app requires the user to enter the current location either by manually searching or by pressing a button to automatically detect the location. I've done the search part using `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`, but for the detection part I'm confused between the above mentioned classes. To my knowledge, `PlaceDetectionClient` provides details about the actual building, like a business, and `FusedLocationProviderClient` uses various sensors to detect the location. Aside from the building detail thing, what's the difference between the two? Which one is more reliable and easier to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what do you need. If you need user location in your app, better way is to rely on latitude and longitude, so I believe it is better use from FusedLocation which provides exactly what you need. 
PlaceDetectionClient is API to detect places where user is nearby i.e check-in feature in current place. I am not sure it is what you really need.

Comment: Right. I figured out PlaceDetectionClient uses likelihood feature to return a list of most likely places. I did the right thing for manual searching, right?

Comment: @Nithin Right. But if I help you, you should upvote my answer and check as correct on the left side. Dont leave your question opened :)